# UIView container disappears after adding child view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tab bar controller that has two tabs. One is a regular UIViewController and the other is a navigation controller. The navigation controller, I am able to push another view controller on it with a custom inputContainerView with no problems. But when I put a navigationViewController (name from mapbox) on the first tab as a child view, the custom inputContainerView no longer shows up. Even after I remove the child view controller from the first tab.

Adding child to tab 1

```
...
    addChild(navigationViewController)
    navigationViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
    view.addSubview(navigationViewController.view)
    navigationViewController.didMove(toParent: self)

}

func navigationViewControllerDidDismiss(_ navigationViewController: NavigationViewController, byCanceling canceled: Bool) {
    navigationViewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
    navigationViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    navigationViewController.removeFromParent()
}
```

tab 2

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get { return inputContainerView }
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { return true }
```

The sequence I am trying to achieve is to add a child view controller to the first tab (navigationViewController which is named this from mapbox) click on the second tab and push a ui view controller on with the inputContainerView showing up. It shows up fine before I add the child view on the first tab but disappears after that

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve here. you adding NavController as a child and then adding NavControllers View as a subview to current Controllers view !!! can you please provide more info?

Comment: I edited with more details, let me know if there is anything confusing

Answer (score 0):

this is what the documentation says:

This method creates a parent-child relationship between the current view controller and the object in the childController parameter. This relationship is necessary when embedding the child view controller’s view into the current view controller’s content. *`If the new child view controller is already the child of a container view controller, it is removed from that container before being added.`*

Check the Highlighted part.

Comment: The new child view controller (navigationViewController) is not a child of any view controller before I make it one of tab 1. But if the inputContainerView is removed because I put the navigationViewController on, how do I put it back?